# PHP Buttons inside loop

Tags: php, button

I have a problem and I don't know how to sove it.I have an inventory table that contains an id (that is assign to a user)column and id_item column (that is assign to an item from items table) and an items table that also contains an id table.

More specifically this is what my database contains:
items table:

```
id  name 
1   Dagger
2   Staff
3   Wood Shield
```

Each with his unique id.

Inventory table:

```
id  id_item     username    name
1   3           cristi          Wood Shield
2   1           motoc           Dagger
2   2           motoc           Staff
```

The id is from every user id and id_item is the item's id from items table.

Problem:
Let's say I'm logged in as motoc who has 2 weapons in his inventory. Til now everything is fine. I want to make a button for every item that he has. The buttons are there but not working properly. When I click the first one is shows me ssss1 which is correct but when I press the second one nothing hapens. I want to show me ssss2 more specifically the next $row1['id_item'].

I really don't know how to solve this.
Thank you.

This is what i've tried:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']."");
    $sth1->execute();
    while($row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ".$row1['id_item']."");
        $sth->execute();
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $ss = print $row1["id_item"];
?>

<form id='<?php echo $row1["id_item"]; ?>' method="POST" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="refid" value="add" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit<?php echo $row1["id_item"]; ?>" value="Add" />
</form>

<?php
    }

    if (isset($_POST["submit$ss"])) {
        $refid = intval($_POST["refid"]);
        $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']."");
        $sth1->execute();
        $row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "ssss".$row1['id_item'];      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad way of building your form. Since you're building a "personalized" form for EVERY item, there's no need to create dynamic field names, just a hidden form field:

```
<form ... >
    <input type="hidden" name="id_item" value="<?php echo $row1['id_item'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="refid" value="add" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Then you simply check `$_POST['id_item']` in the form handling code, instead of having to look for every single possible `submit1`, `submit2`, etc...

As well, your form handling code is running within the same context as the form generation code, before the form has even had a chance to be displayed and get a user click. You should at least have somethign like

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    ... handle form here ...
    echo "ssss...";
}
```

so the item info retrieval only runs when the form actually HAS been submitted.

Comment: How can I echo $row1['id_item'] inside if statement not as value of the input? It is a matter of scope I think

Comment: php's scope is at the function/method level. `if()` is not a separate block as far as variables are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.  I'm kinda confused on exactly what you want to happen, but I think this will do it.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['id']);
    $sth1->execute();
    while ($row = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = " . $row['id_item']);
        $sth->execute();
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $ss = $row["id_item"];
        ?>

        <form id='<?php echo $ss; ?>' method="post" action="?show">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $ss; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>

    <?php
    }

    if (isset($_GET["show"]) && isset($_POST['item_id'])) {
        echo "ssss" . $_POST['item_id'];
    }

}
```

I cleaned up some of the code and changed the way the form was built.  I also changed the PHP code at the bottom to check for the changes in the form.

I will tell you now though.  The way you designed the database should be changed.  Keeping that updated will be a pain in the ass.  You should use an items table, a users table, and have a pivot table between them since it is a many-to-many relationship.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very very much searsaw. Works perfect. I will search more about pivot table. Thank you again

Comment: How can I echo $ss inside the if statement because I want to make an UPDATE statement $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE attributes SET gold = :gold WHERE id = :id"); and if I put it inside input type item_id the updade is made at every page refresh and I want the update after I click a button. Thanks