# Ajax Posting always same value

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on button groups which are retrieving by PHP echo from database and need to post values by Ajax. This is shortly about creating product main groups, sub groups and products.

This is the code for creating and listing buttons:

```
 echo '
<a class="altgrup_al">
<input type="hidden" name="data_id" id="data_id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="san_RECno" id="san_RECno" value="'.$san_RECno.'">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" style="margin-
left:5px; margin-bottom:5px; height:80px; width:80px; white-
space:normal;">'.$san_isim.'</button></a>';
```

And this is the ajax code for posting:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".altgrup_al").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
  var deger = document.getElementById('data_id').value;
  var sth_fatura_no = document.getElementById('sth_fatura_no').value;
  var san_RECno = document.getElementById('san_RECno').value; 
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "altgrup_al.php", 
    data: {deger:deger, sth_fatura_no:sth_fatura_no, san_RECno:san_RECno}, 
    success: function(result){ 
      $("#alt_tablo").html(result); 
    }
   });
    });
   });
  </script>
```

i tried also data-id attribute but in any style of ajax posting,

```
var san_RECno = document.getElementById('san_RECno').value;
```

this value = 1.

But when i list buttons and show the value of `san_RECno`, each button shows its own id number.

I'm not good on JavaScript enough so i need help why always posting same (1) id number.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have several buttons with same id - you're doing it wrong. `id` must be unique on the page.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in an `a` tag? Attach the click event to the button.

Comment: Is your html code is place in loop?

Comment: Each button retrieving different id  according to the mysql table and the echo is in while loop.

Comment: I am not sure but i think the san_RECno is taking the first loop element value (id=1). Doesn't matter which button i click. Can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for creating and listing buttons :

Also look for [PHP Buttons inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727284/php-buttons-inside-loop)

```
<?php
$inc = 1; //define a varible which increment in loop
loop_start{ //loop like while,for,foreach

echo '
<a class="altgrup_al" data-id="'.$inc.'">
<input type="hidden" name="data_id" id="data_id'.$inc.'" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="san_RECno" id="san_RECno'.$inc.'" value="'.$san_RECno.'">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:5px; height:80px; width:80px; white-space:normal;">'.$san_isim.'</button></a>'

$inc++;
}
?>
```

And this is the ajax code for posting:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".altgrup_al").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); 
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          var deger = $('#data_id'+id).val();
          var sth_fatura_no = $('#sth_fatura_no'+id).val();
          var san_RECno = $('#san_RECno'+id).val(); 
          $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "altgrup_al.php", 
            data: {deger:deger, sth_fatura_no:sth_fatura_no, san_RECno:san_RECno}, 
            success: function(result){ 
              $("#alt_tablo").html(result); 
            }
           });
    });
});
</script>
```

> use jquery instead of javascript for [getting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box) if you have already jquery library

Comment: AMAZING..!! Thank you so much.

Comment: With this help the sub_groups of products are listing perfectly as buttons so how can i use this way for sub_group buttons? Main-Group buttons -> Sub_Group Buttons -> Products. and each list has one button which turns the list back. Foreaxmple after clicking main buttons, sub buttons are listing with one button which will turn back to main groups. Any idea how to do whole working system?

Comment: please create a chat room for further explanation @Serter

Comment: I can't create new chat room cause of being new here.

Comment: better i will ask it as a new question

Answer (score 2):

**step 1 :** make your hidden text box with dynamic ID (if you are using loop then put its count with same name (like: id="data_id+ echo php variable") and call JS method with arguments like

> ONCLICK="saveData($('#data_id+ echo php variable).val()')"

**Step 2 :**

```
function saveData(var dataid)
var deger = dataid;
 $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "altgrup_al.php", 
    data: {deger:deger}, 
    success: function(result){ 
      $("#alt_tablo").html(result); 
    }
   });
```

Comment: this is for POST one variable only . you can make it for more text values with more arguments